# Angular, Disable button validator

Tags: angular

I hope you have a great day.

I'm getting stuck within creating a validator funciton. I want to disable a button if the text area is empty or if it contains "\n\n/Admin".

What I have done now is :

.html file

```
    <textarea class="g-input form-control" formControlName="messageBody" id="messageBody" tabindex="0" rows="4">
    </textarea>

    <button data-color="purple" type="submit" [disabled]="">
      <div>Send</div>
    </button>
```

.ts file

```
  initForm() {
this.form = this.fb.group({
  messageBody: [`\n\n/admin`, Validators.required, ]
});
```

I would really apprecaite if someone could help. Have a wounderful day.

Comment: Try `[disabled]="form.invalid"`. See how that works for you.

Comment: angular documentation has exactly what you need: https://angular.io/guide/form-validation and specifically the `forbiddenNameValidator` which is used as an example there of a custom validator: https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#defining-custom-validators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.ts file should be like below

```
import { Component, VERSION, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {
  AbstractControl,
  FormBuilder,
  FormGroup,
  ValidatorFn,
  Validators,
} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  form: FormGroup;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.initForm();
  }
  initForm() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      messageBody: [`\n\n/Admin`,[Validators.required,this.validateMessageBody()]],
    });
  }

  validateMessageBody(): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } => {
      if(control.value){
        if(control.value.search('\n\n/Admin') !==-1){
          return { invalidMessageBody: { value: control.value }};
        }
        return null;
      }
      return null;
    };
  }
  get messageBody() {
    return this.form.get('messageBody');
  }
}
```

.html file should be like below

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
<textarea class="g-input form-control" formControlName="messageBody" id="messageBody" tabindex="0" rows="4">
</textarea>
<button data-color="purple" type="submit" [disabled]="messageBody?.errors?.required || messageBody?.errors?.invalidMessageBody">
  <div>Send</div>
</button>

</form>
```

View demo https://angular-ivy-cijsfx.stackblitz.io